# How to give an div tag outside of another element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Give an div outside of another div using jQuery

```
<div class = "inner" >Test </div>
```

Make it to

```
<div class= "outside">
    <div class = "inner" >Test </div>
</div>
```

I want to build an div outside of existing element(div class = "inner") using jQuery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.inner').wrap($('<div/>',{'class':'outside'}));
```

should do it

Comment: Or simply `$('.inner').wrap('<div class="outside" />');`

Comment: @Jusnit `$('.inner').detach().replaceAll('.outside');`

Comment: @itea: Thanks itea, I have seen unwrap also, $('.inner').unwrap('<div class="outside" />');